# Унарный оператор, split с Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, split

Смотрите, например у меня есть такое выражение
`string expression = "(-1+-2)+(20*2/-4)";`

Мне нужно его превратить в

```
string[] split = { "(" , "-1" , "+" , "-2" ,")" ,  "+" , "(" , "20" , "*" , "2" , "/" , "-4" , ")"};
```

Что я пробовал

```
 string[] split = Regex.Split(line, @"([*()\^\/]|(?<!E)[\+\-])");
 split = split.Where(empty => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(empty)).ToArray();
```

Comment: конкретно только это математическое выражение, или вообще любое может быть?

Comment: @aepot вообще любое может быть. Это как пример.

Comment: Либо вы поменяете правила, потому что текущие под регеспы не подходят, либо вам в правильный разбор и построение выражений надо. Но вот это +-2 это конечно надо будет постараться регулярками описать правила, когда минус нужно считать числом, а когда операцией.

Comment: @AK как ни странно, регулярка съела унарные операторы как надо и не подавилась, ни при `+-`, ни при `-+`.

Comment: Вложенные скобки могут быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
string expression = "(-1+-2)+(20*2/-4)";
string[] tokens = Regex.Split(expression, @"(\b[-+*\/]|[+-]?\d+|[-+*\/()])").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", tokens));
```

```
( -1 + -2 ) + ( 20 * 2 / -4 )
```

Comment: Прикольно, я думал сложнее выйдет регулярка.

Comment: Если в выражении убрать унарные `+`, `-`, то ой... `1+2` парсится как `1`, `+2`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, исправил ошибку