# Исключение из строки скобок в Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Спличу строку таким образом:

```
string[] Funct = Regex.Split(Function.Task, @"-?([\W])");
```

Почему в массиве появляются "", и остаются скобки, если сплитить такое выражение: 5*6-(2+х)

P.S Массив должен получиться такого вида: "5", "*", "6", "-", "2", "+", "x". Естественно, строковый.

Comment: а почему не должны оставаться скобки в данном случае?

Comment: может так? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266812/373567 или так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1264362/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скобки остаются, потому что вы их "захватили" с помощью захватывающей подмаски.

Вы можете использовать

```cs
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"[^()\w]+|\w+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

**Подробности**

- `[^()\w]+` - один и более символов, отличных от буквенно-цифровых символов или символов нижнего подчёркивания, а также `(` и `)`
- `|` - или
- `\w+` - один и более буквенно-цифровых символов или символов нижнего подчёркивания

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%28%29%5Cw%5D%2B%7C%5Cw%2B&i=5*6-%282%2B%D1%85%29):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]